# Salesforce DX - Omni Channel

Tags: salesforcedx, omnichannel

How is Omni-Channel deployed in DX ? Complete? Lots of manual work ? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SF StackExchange, AFAIK Omnichannel configurations are not deployable by change sets alone and thus also not supported by SFDX.

> "We do not have any option to include the configuration done in Omni-channel to migrate/deploy to production..."

[Success idea link.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LhGwAAK)